# Why does EaseUS Todo give Linux Emergency Disk error?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, clone, easeus-todo-backup

I'm using EaseUS ToDo Backup to clone an HDD to an SSD. Partway throught the Disk/Partition Clone process, I get this error:

```
Linux emergency disk cannot support GPT disk. 
Please create WinPE emergency disk and try again.
```

The only part of that I understand is that Linux is an OS that's not on any of my drives.

After I click "OK", the screen says

```
Initializing clone, please wait...
```

Which is contradicted by the progress bar reading `100%` and the non-greyed-out button that says `Finish`.

Why is this situation happening, and how do I handle it?

Comment: Apparently there are two options for creating the **emergency** disk or USB drive: put a Linux OS on the media or put WinPE OS on the media. This has nothing to do with your current OS. Either should work, so set WinPE as the reinstallation media OS.

Comment: Where do I change that setting?

Comment: Look at the directions. https://www.easeus.com/support/todo-backup/create-emergency-disk.html

Answer (score 0):

When you select to make an "Emergency Disk" you are given the option to make a WINPE or a LINUX disk.  If you don't have Linux, always select WINPE.

This option is located in one of the pull down menus.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all the partitions in second disk and do the clone